# Firebase function unable to be imported

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently working on a web app with Firebase as our DB and React as our frontend. *Note that I  am only setting up the DB right now, there is no connection right now.*

I'm trying to setup Firebase in our React project, however I keep getting greeted with the following error:

`export 'getFireStore' (imported as 'getFireStore') was not found in 'firebase/firestore' (possible exports: AbstractUserDataWriter, Bytes, CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED, CollectionReference, DocumentReference, DocumentSnapshot, FieldPath, FieldValue, Firestore, FirestoreError, GeoPoint, LoadBundleTask, Query, QueryConstraint, QueryDocumentSnapshot, QuerySnapshot, SnapshotMetadata, Timestamp, Transaction, WriteBatch, _DatabaseId, _DocumentKey, _EmptyAppCheckTokenProvider, _EmptyAuthCredentialsProvider, _FieldPath, _cast, _debugAssert, _isBase64Available, _logWarn, _validateIsNotUsedTogether, addDoc, arrayRemove, arrayUnion, clearIndexedDbPersistence, collection, collectionGroup, connectFirestoreEmulator, deleteDoc, deleteField, disableNetwork, doc, documentId, enableIndexedDbPersistence, enableMultiTabIndexedDbPersistence, enableNetwork, endAt, endBefore, ensureFirestoreConfigured, executeWrite, getDoc, getDocFromCache, getDocFromServer, getDocs, getDocsFromCache, getDocsFromServer, getFirestore, increment, initializeFirestore, limit, limitToLast, loadBundle, namedQuery, onSnapshot, onSnapshotsInSync, orderBy, query, queryEqual, refEqual, runTransaction, serverTimestamp, setDoc, setIndexConfiguration, setLogLevel, snapshotEqual, startAfter, startAt, terminate, updateDoc, waitForPendingWrites, where, writeBatch)`

This is how my setup file looks like currently:

```js
// Importing functions from packages
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFireStore } from 'firebase/firestore'

// Boilerplate API setup
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.apiKey,
  authDomain: process.env.authDomain,
  projectId: process.env.projectID,
  storageBucket: process.env.storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId: process.messagingSenderID,
  appId: process.env.appID,
  measurementId: process.env.measurementID
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Exported so our DB can be accessed from other files.
export const db = getFireStore(app);
```

I understand that it's complaining about the `getFireStore` import which is odd because I am following documentation as well as videos and everybody else is doing the same.

Comment: The error is telling you that `firebase/firestore` doesn't export anything called `getFireStore`.  It's not clear to me why you think it does, because that isn't covered in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) anywhere.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0

I was following this documentation whilst setting up

Comment: You have a typo.  It's getFirestore.  No capital s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `getFirestore` not `getFireStore`.